# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_3" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 128, 1280), found shape=(None, 1280)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am building a 1d CNN model which can input 10 second long ecg frames and detect a specific heart disorder. I have 130,464 training data and 32,616 testing data. My input data is of the shape (num_samples, 1280)

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, Flatten, Dense, BatchNormalization,    RepeatVector

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=512, kernel_size=8, activation='relu', input_shape=(128, 1280), name="1_conv1d"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
# model.add(Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=6, activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 1280), name="2_conv1d"))
# model.add(BatchNormalization())
# model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
# model.add(Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=4, activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 1280)))
# model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 1), name="3_conv1d"))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, Y_train))
# model.fit(train_data, epochs=4, batch_size=1024)

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=4, batch_size=1024)

test_loss, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)
```

I had commented out a lot of the layers hoping that it would help me pinpoint the error. However, the error thrown is the same.

```
ValueError: in user code:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1401, in train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1384, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1373, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1150, in train_step
    y_pred = self(x, training=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/input_spec.py", line 298, in   assert_input_compatibility
    raise ValueError(

ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_3" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 128, 1280), found shape=(None, 1280)
```

I followed the advice from previous questions posted of similar issues. It didn't help. I also tried changing the batch sizes and input shapes, didn't help.

My next step is to try reshaping the input since the error says it received (None, 1280) instead of (None, 128, 1280). But I don't know how to. Any help on this?

Comment: What is the output of `X_train.shape`?`X_train` should be a 3 dimensional arrray ie `len(X_train.shape)` should output 3. Otherwise your model is incorrect. Seems that you have a 2D array thus you should not do a `Conv1D` but rather directly use `Dense`.

Comment: You're right, X_train is a 2d array. Taking your advice, if I replace Conv1D layers with Dense layer, will that reduce the strength of my model to detect potential heart disorders in this case?

Comment: It depends on how you want the model to behave. Different model definitions yield different results. Also perhaps your data is just a flattened array of an image. If so, you could still use `Conv1D` but you will have to reshape back to the normal image pixels, eg `X.reshape(-1, 40, 32)` I do  not know what the image dim was, just used `40,32` But If this information is not given, you should definitely not reshape. Just use fully connected layers and you will get the accuracy you want

Comment: You should first worry about making a model that actually runs, before worrying about any "strength".

Comment: @Onyambu, My data is 2d arrays filled up of binary data representing ecg signals. I still want to use 1d Conv layers, because somehow it worked in the past when i was working with a dataset way smaller(in total 6500 samples) than the current one. Back then too my data was 2d and it delivered an accuracy of 65%. But thanks for the help

Comment: You can use Dense and still get accuracy of 65+. The issue about Conv1d is that Xtrain must be a 3 d array. Yes each individual image is a 2d array, but the whole training dataset must be 3 d array. If not then You cannot use `conv1d`. please read the documentation of `conv1d`

Comment: In the documentation it is clearly writen that *input: A Tensor of rank at least 3. Must be of type `float16`, `float32`, or    `float64`*